# how to get Magento baseUrl through Javascript and then use it in jquery.hello-lightbox.min?

Tags: javascript, magento, base-url

i'm trying to get Magento BaseUrl through javascript in head.phtml file, and then use it in jquery.hello-lightbox.min file, where i need the baseUrl to get some images.

Here's what i have in head.phtml file:

```
<?php $baseUrl = $this->getBaseUrl() ; ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

var baseUrl = <?php echo $baseUrl ; ?>

function getBaseUrl(baseUrl)

</script>
```

Then in /js/jquery.hello-lightbox.min i have:

```
(function($){

function getBaseUrl(baseurl)
{
var domain = baseurl
}

var urrl = 'http://'+domain+'/skin/frontend/default/customtheme/images/lightbox/';

  $.fn.lightBox=function(settings)settings=jQuery.extend({overlayBgColor:'#000',overlayOpacity:0.8,fixedNavigation:false,imageLoading: urrl+'lightbox-ico-loading.gif',imageBtnPrev:urrl+'lightbox-btn-prev.gif', . . . . . . . . . .
```

But this doesn't work. In fact it seems like i can't even pass the php variable $baseUrl to var baseUrl in head.phtml

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

There are syntax errors in your main code. I think what you want is to define a function that returns the base URL like so:

```
<?php $baseUrl = $this->getBaseUrl() ; ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

function getBaseUrl() { return '<?php echo $baseUrl; ?>'; } 

</script>
```

then use it in JavaScript: (get rid of the `function getBaseUrl(baseurl) ...` stuff there)

```
var urrl = 'http://'+getBaseUrl()+'/skin/frontend/default/customtheme/images/lightbox/';
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but what you suggest breaks the ligthbox functionality. If i leave the function: function getBaseUrl(baseurl){} in jquery.hello-lightbox.min then the ligthbox functionality works but can't get the Base URL, if i checked with firebug the URL in the css line shows as: url("http://undefined/skin/frontend/default/... I think we are close. Any other clue?

Answer (score 2):

Try to put quotes around the JS var you're setting via the php echo:

`var baseUrl = '<?php echo $baseUrl ; ?>'`

Answer (score 2):

You can call base url via these simple steps throughout the store in every javascript  / php file.

Open your theme's  **page/html/head.phtml** and add following code in the **HEAD** tag in the last line:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var BASE_URL = '<?php echo  Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>';
</script>
```

Now you can use BASE_URL variable in every javascript code in your theme files to get magento base url in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use inline Javascript, you can always just add it as an attribute to a div or something along those lines.

For example, I'll often add a html element like this:

```
<div class="my-class" data-storeurl="<?php echo  Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>">
....
</div>
```

And then in my Javascript (jQuery in this case), I'll just add something like:

```
var current_store = $('.store-redirect').attr('data-storeurl');
```

It's handy for AJAX calls where you want to run the call on the correct store's url.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Javascript won't pass variables between files like that. You don't need to use PHP in this case, just do this:

```
var urrl = 'http://'+window.location.host+'/skin/frontend/default/customtheme/images/lightbox/';
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. The baseUrl is correctly generated by $baseUrl = $this->getBaseUrl() ;  The problem is that i can't pass it to the js variable

Comment: Thanks but that is the same as adding:  var domain = document.domain; and then var urrl = 'http://'+domain+'/skin/frontend/default/helloresponsive/images/lightbox/';  Which doesn't brind the baseUrl, it just brings the host root URL, and i need the baseUrl in this case...

Comment: Can you see if that function in /js/jquery.hello-lightbox.min is actually running by placing an alert?

Comment: No, it is not running, that's why i'm in doubt if this can be done by placing a function in a js library. Maybe i'm in the wrong way...

Comment: Try moving the function outside of the anonymous function: (function($){

Comment: something like alert('hi'); does not run?

Comment: No, when i place the function in jquery.hello-lightbox.min the lightbox functionality breaks

Answer (score -3):

Magento : Get Base Url , Skin Url , Media Url , Js Url , Store Url and Current Url:

1. Get Base Url `:Mage::getBaseUrl();`
2. Get Skin Url `:Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_SKIN);`

   1. Unsecure Skin Url `:$this->getSkinUrl('images/imagename.jpg');`
   2. Secure Skin Url `:$this->getSkinUrl('images/imagename.gif', array('_secure'=>true));`
3. Get Media Url `:Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);`
4. Get Js Url `:Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_JS);`
5. Get Store Url `:Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);`
6. Get Current Url `:Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();`

Get Url in cms pages or static blocks:

1. Get Base Url `:{{store url=""}}`
2. Get Skin Url `:{{skin url='images/imagename.jpg'}}`
3. Get Media Url `:{{media url='/imagename.jpg'}}
4. Get Store Url `:{{store url='mypage.html'}}`